# How to write a dynamic Xpath using Javascript / Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, xpath, puppeteer

How we can write a dynamic xpath for puppeteer Automation? For example I have two xpaths with same right and left boundary as you can see below:

```
//*[@id='gridBodyTable_primaryField_{7B7C22C8-9EBE-EB11-A84A-000D3A95E99D}_0']
//*[@id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{051E841E-B9BE-EB11-A84A-000D3A95E99D}_0"]
```

The numbers/alphabets inside the curly brackets `{7B7C22C8-9EBE-EB11-A84A-000D3A95E99D}` are dynamically generated. However the rest of the body always remains the same.

Comment: the path in xpath is a string .. so, use any methods you like to create that string ... `+` ... `.concat` ... template literals ... the choices are as varied as any string you create anywhere in javascript

Comment: Thanks for your reply could you please provide me with an example. 
Thanks

Comment: `var variable = "this part is variable"; var string = "this part is hard coded " + variable + " this is also hard coded";` guess what string becomes!!

Comment: I still couldn’t understand. How can I covert this xpath //[@id='gridBodyTable_primaryField_{7B7C22C8-9EBE-EB11-A84A-000D3A95E99D}_0'] into variable and string ? Sorry I am new to coding. Thanks for your time

Comment: variable part is "{7B7C22C8-9EBE-EB11-A84A-000D3A95E99D}" fixed part is not that

Comment: Hi @Bravo I tried the way you advised me, but unfortunately it's not working, i declared a global variable and then amend that into my xapth as below:
xpath : "//*[@id='gridBodyTable_primaryField_{'"+ variable+"'}_0']",

could you please advise me where i am doing a mistake ?

Comment: I haven't advised you how - I advised how to build a string using static and dynamic "parts" - if you can't do that from what I've said, then the issue is deeper - anyway, the answer below shows what you need to do

Answer (score 0):

See [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Some variants:

```js
const ids = [
  '7B7C22C8-9EBE-EB11-A84A-000D3A95E99D',
  '051E841E-B9BE-EB11-A84A-000D3A95E99D',
];

for (const id of ids) {
  const xpath = `//*[@id='gridBodyTable_primaryField_{${id}}_0']`;
  // ...
}
```

```js
function createXPath(id) {
  return `//*[@id='gridBodyTable_primaryField_{${id}}_0']`;
}

const xpath1 = createXPath('7B7C22C8-9EBE-EB11-A84A-000D3A95E99D');
const xpath2 = createXPath('051E841E-B9BE-EB11-A84A-000D3A95E99D');
// ...
```